# "http: TLS handshake error" from grafana logs when trying to restart grafana

Tags: grafana

When am starting grafana 4.3.2 ,am getting handshake error in the grafana logs and grafana page is not loading showing certificate error.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a packet capture tool to capture the TLS handshake and then analyze the handshake messages to find the error code that is occurring during the handshake. You could then cross-reference that code against the list found here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2012/10/05/ssltls-alert-protocol-the-alert-codes/